# MySql on Azure Throwing Connection Timeouts

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu, azure, loopbackjs

I have 2 Virtual Machines on Azure in the same Virtual Network.

One virtual machine runs a NodeJs process which is responsible for MySQL operations.

Other virtual machine runs a MySQL instance. I can connect to it from the other VM and from the NodeJs process fine.

Sometimes it will fail and throw an error about Connection timeout when acquiring a connection from the pool.

My connection string uses a local IP address from within the Virtual Network to access the database so it should have this much delay to exceed a 10 second timeout. When it works it's rapid, I mean really fast! But sometimes it just breaks and randomly starts working again. Anyone ever come across this?

If it's any help this is a MySQL instance based on Ubuntu Server 15.10.

Exception:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
    "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "fatal": true,
    "stack": "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
            at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:375:13)
            at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
            at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
            at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:327:8)
            at Timer.unrefTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:412:13)
            --------------------
            at Protocol._enqueue (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
            at Protocol.handshake (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
            at PoolConnection.connect (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
            at Pool.getConnection (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:45:23)
            at MySQL.executeSQL (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:200:12)
            at projectdir/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/node_modules/loopback-connector/lib/sql.js:408:10
            at projectdir/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:175:9
            at doNotify (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:93:49)
            at MySQL.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:116:5)
            at MySQL.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (projectdir/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:91:8)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381010/php-mysql-connection-error-implementing-retry-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a process running all the time and when it idles for a while the connections in the pool are in a sleeping state. Eventually MySQL purges those connections based on the wait_timeout setting in my.cnf. Once this happens and I try to use a connection it will fail because the module assumes the connection is still live and tries to use it only to get a timeout or connection exception.

To prevent this you can either overwrite the mysql module code to support "connection lifetime" in the pool or stop using the pool and manage your own connections.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there are 2 situations may raise your issue.

The connections reaches the max_connection number of MySQL server, and there are no available connections for a new connection client. In this situation, you may check your code, whether you release the connection after MySQL operations.

On the other hand, when you get the timeout exception, you may login on Azure manage portal, in monitor page of your VM portal, to check whether the metrics reach the bottleneck of the VM which will also occur your issue. In this situation, you can scale on  your VM to enlarge your VM hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js mysql module has a few [options](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options).
One of these options is the 'connectTimeout', which defaults to 10000ms (which is roughly 10 seconds).

If nothing is done within those 10 seconds, the connection closes automatically.

What the solution could be for you problem, is using [pooling connections](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections).

With this, you create a connection pool. Everytime a query needs to be executed, it takes a connection from the pool uses it and when it expires it automatically returns to the pool, ready to be restarted, thus no more connection timeout errors.

Comment: I am already using the pool. I've did a bit of digging and my latest hypothesis is that the MySQL server kills sleeping connections and NodeJs pool holds on to them without knowing they have been terminated and when I request it fails because the connection is dead. How can I make the pool get rid of the connections from the pool after a certain amount of time? So that they line up with the MySQL cleaning routine and hence both parties would be up to date

Comment: I'd like to know this too!